# Getting Shared Preference in a Fragment

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I was having some problem with shared preference in Android fragment. In my MainActivity onLoad, I am checking the shared preference, if it is true, then I open up fragment A.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("EULA_SHARED_PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean status = prefs.getBoolean("show_eula_key", false);
    if(status == true){
        EulaFragment eulaFragment = new EulaFragment();
        eulaFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), null);
}
```

In my fragment A, upon Accept button onClick, I update the shared preference to false:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("show_eula_key", false).commit();
            dismiss();
```

However, even though I selected accepted and restarted the app, when I relaunch the app, it keeps open up the fragment A. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use two different files:

> SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("EULA_SHARED_PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE);

and

> SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

You must use the same at both. (tip: an Activity is a context)

Comment: How can I make it the same file? One is activity one is fragment. I tried to use the first method in fragment but it throws me error message

Comment: It is a fragment. I am getting cannot resolve getApplicationContext() error

Comment: as @JonasLochmann said you should use getContext() it is available in fragment

Comment: To refine use fragment.getActivity() you will get the reference

Answer (score 1):

In Fragment A

```
SharedPreferences prefs =getActivity().getSharedPreferences("EULA_SHARED_PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE);
        prefs.edit().putBoolean("show_eula_key",false).apply();
```

Answer (score 0):

use something like this

```
editor.putBoolean("show_eula_key", false).apply();
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you are getting  show_eula_key from EULA_SHARED_PREFERENCE and saving in default preference, you have to data from preference exactly you are saving it

Comment: using stackoverflow application and after refresh post all answers gathered around. my bad

Answer (score 0):

Change your second code to

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getContext().getSharedPreferences("EULA_SHARED_PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean("show_eula_key", false).apply();
```

Comment: It is a fragment though

Comment: yes, thats why we are using 'getContext()'. Please check edit

Comment: @guest176969 you can mark it as the correct answer if it did